# Laravel: getting status code 255 while updating composer file

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

Working on laravel project.

When I tried to run `php artisan serve` the command was just ignored, So i updated the `composer.json` file with 
`composer update` command.

then i got,
[@php artisan package:discover --ansi error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb5ps.jpg)

at last it end up with,
[@php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWdWl.jpg)

Sorry for not being able to post images directly.

Comment: Copy paste your console logs

Comment: links are referenced to the image files... please check that once

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: artisan serve didn't work for me either when I was using Laravel 5.5.*. So, do a `cd public` on your command line inside your Laravel project folder and run this-  `php -S localhost:8000`. Your local development server will get started on port 8000. `php artisan serve` would have done the same.

Comment: Try do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840960/script-php-artisan-packagediscover-handling-the-post-autoload-dump-event-retur/53673749#53673749

Comment: Here is the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840960/script-php-artisan-packagediscover-handling-the-post-autoload-dump-event-retur/53673749#53673749