# package:discover error code 255 after pulling repo and composer update

Tags: composer-php

I pulled a repo with a Laravel app and tried

```
composer update
```

but it exits with

```
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

I found the following and regenerated the .env file and the key:

[Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840960/script-php-artisan-packagediscover-handling-the-post-autoload-dump-event-retur)

It did not help anything. I also got the original .env file from the server which also did not help.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

ok now it works. What I did:

1.Created a fresh project with

```
laravel new test
```

2.Copied the composer.json from the not working project to my fresh project

3.did run:

```
composer update
```

(which did not have any problems in that fresh project, who knows why..)

4.did overwrite the vendor folder inside the not working project with the vendor folder from the fresh project after running composer update (see 3.)

5.did run:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

6.did run:

```
php artisan serve
```

7.app is running without any errors.

Comment: It did help me back in the days exactly like this. If anybody has anything to add, please elaborate/add a better solution.