# composer dump-autoload error after fresh Laravel install

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-7

After a fresh install of Laravel 7, I snagged an error during the installation of google/cloud plugin.

My steps of what I did:

```
laravel new
composer require google/cloud
```

Then while installing, I encountered this error

```
Package manifest generated successfully.
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code -1073741819
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I've also noticed that the .env file is missing. I did update my global composer with `composer selfupdate` and same error still occurs.

Comment: Did you do a composer install / update before ?

Comment: @iamlux20 Try `php artisan clear` command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840960/script-php-artisan-packagediscover-handling-the-post-autoload-dump-event-retur)

Comment: @Takachi, yes I did a global composer update before.

Comment: @HarpalSingh I don't see the point of running `php artisan clear` on a clean slate project (yet)

Comment: @N69S, no. Even though I added .env from copying the .env.example file, it still wouldn't progress to the dumpautoload