# Can't create new laravel project | package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 PHP versions on my PC. In the past I was using PHP 8 (8.1.13) like this to install laravel:

```
C:\PHP8\php8.exe C:\composer\composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel Project-Name
```

It was working for 2 projects, which I installed a few months ago. Today I try to create a new laravel project, but it tells me I need to upgrade my composer:

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.3.1] require composer-runtime-api ^2.2 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.3.1].
```

The most recent version for laravel is now 10 and it seems it needs a higher version of composer. Now I dont want to upgrade composer itself because I am not sure how this will affect the other projects, or is it safe to do so?

My solution was to install the same laravel version, which I used in the other projects, so I did this:

```
C:\PHP8\php8.exe C:\composer\composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.29 Project-Name
```

This for some reason gives me this error:

```
package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

I tried now all solutions, which I found online, but nothing works, any idea?

**UPDATE:**

Setting up now everything fresh in a venv via phpStorm. I use now the newest version of composer and my PHP8 installation. This leads to the same error:

```
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

Comment: Take a look at these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840960/script-php-artisan-packagediscover-handling-the-post-autoload-dump-event-retur

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but when you are using different PHP versions you should start to use docker. https://www.docker.com/

Comment: @Aless55 I was this already, I cannot even create the laravel project and I am on windows

Comment: @Foobar I do not understand how exactly docker helps here. I first need to generate the source files on my machine before I can write a Dockerfile and the docker-compose.yml, but generating the source files does not work for me.

Comment: You could also setup different windows machines with docker not only laravel projects.

Comment: I would simply try and upgrade composer, I am not sure why the old versions should break, if they do, you can simply reinstall an older composer version or even better, upgrade the old projects

Comment: @Aless55 I did not know this, will research on how to do it. Thanks

Comment: `sudo composer self-update`